# Extracting an href's text from an html document

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, xml, xpath

I'm trying to parse this piece of HTML:

```
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(0); return false;">A few years ago,</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;">I felt like I was stuck in a rut,</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(5000); return false;">so I decided to follow in the footsteps</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(7000); return false;">of the great American philosopher, Morgan Spurlock,</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(10000); return false;">and try something new for 30 days.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

I want to know how to get the text in label, such as: "A few years ago,"

I can get text in `"<a> text </a>",`

But I do not know how to get  "A few years ago," in the label of  `"<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(0); return false;">A few years ago,</a> "`

```
<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(0); return false;">  
<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;">
....................
```

There are different about only `onclick="seekVideo(....);`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and easy XPath expression whose evaluation produces exactly the wanted text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use XPath: `/div/p/a[1]/text()` - selects `a` by index or matching `@onclick` value: `/div/p/a[starts-with(@onclick, 'seekVideo(0)')]/text()`. So both queries return `A few years ago,`.

To get number in `@onclick` `seekVideo` you can use this expression:

```
substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')')
```

e.g.: To find `a` whose `@onclick` `seekVideo` = `0` you can use this XPath:

```
/div/p/a[substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')') = '0']/text()
```

or

```
/div/p/a[number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')')) = 0]/text()
```

So both queries return `A few years ago,`.

Comment: how to get the number in seekVideo(number), if i use "/div/p/a[1]/text() " ?

Comment: how to get the number in seekVideo(number)????

/div/p/a[number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')'))]   
is not right!!!

eg:
<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;">

i want to get "2000",  how to do?

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
string(//div/a[starts-with(@onclick, 'seekVideo(0)')])
```

This expression evaluates the string-value of the first `a` in the XML document that is a child of a `div`, and the string-value of whose `onclick` attribute starts with the string `"seekVideo(0)"`