# iphone ,how to get this label?

Tags: iphone, xml

```
<div>
  <p>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(0); return false;">A few years ago,</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;">I felt like I was stuck in a rut,</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(5000); return false;">so I decided to follow in the footsteps</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(7000); return false;">of the great American philosopher, Morgan Spurlock,</a>
    <a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(10000); return false;">and try something new for 30 days.</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

this is a part of web code  .

i want to know how to get the text in label .  such as:"A few years ago,"

i can get   text in `"<a> text </a>",`

but i do not know how to get  "A few years ago," in label of  `"<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(0); return false;">A few years ago,</a> "`

```
<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(0); return false;">  
<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;">
....................
```

there are different about only `onclick="seekVideo(....);`

`/div/p/a[substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')') = '0']/text()`

can get text like `"A few years ago";`

but now i want to get the number in `seekVideo(number)`????

`/div/p/a[number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')'))]`

is not right!!!

eg: `<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;">`

i want to get "2000", how to do?

sample project or code   is better, thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [libxml2.dylib parse html on iphone , how to do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772803/libxml2-dylib-parse-html-on-iphone-how-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

If its a valid XML (from the example you showed us it is valid XML) you can Parse using NSXMLParser.

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if(!currentString){
        currentString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    }
    [currentString appendString:string];    
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a"]){
        NSLog(@"Text betweeen \"a\" tag %@",currentString);
    }
    [currentString release],currentString =nil;
}
```

To get 0 from seekVideo(0), use

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"a"]){
        NSString* onClickAttribString = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"onclick"];
        NSLog(@"OnClick Attrib: %@",onClickAttribString);
        // seekVideo(0); return false; 
        NSArray* arrayList = [onClickAttribString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]; // gives array of string seperated by space
        NSLog(@"seekvideo %@",[arrayList objectAtIndex:0]);
        //Process seekvideo(0); to get number... use NSScanner
        NSString* seekVideoString = [arrayList objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* numberString = [seekVideoString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]];
        NSLog(@"Number : %@",numberString);
        // if you want numberString converted to integer then [numberString intValue]
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723244/iphone-how-to-select-this-label-------------this web  ,  can you use code framework as same as Kirill Polishchuk and give me answer?

Comment: You said you tried "/div/p/a[number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')'))]" what does that give you ?