# Extracting a value from an html href's attribute

Tags: iphone, html, xml

This is a followup to my previous question: [Extracting an href's text from an html document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723244/iphone-how-to-select-this-label)

How can I get the number in `seekVideo(number)`? For example:

```
<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;"
```

I want to get "2000".

I have tried:

```
NSArray *elements = [xpathParser search:@"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')'))"];
```

But that's not right. How can I do this?

If someone can you use the code framework that [Kirill Polishchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/787016/kirill-polishchuk) provided in this web(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723244/iphone-how-to-select-this-label), it would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone ,how to get this label?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231132/iphone-how-to-get-this-label)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSScanner:

```
int seekVideo = 0;
NSString *testString = @"<a href=\"#\" class=\"transcriptLink\" onclick=\"seekVideo(2000); return false;\"";

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:testString];
[scanner scanUpToString:@"seekVideo(" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanString:@"seekVideo(" intoString:nil];
[scanner scanInt:&seekVideo];

NSLog(@"seekVideo: %d", seekVideo);
```

2011-08-30 07:47:11.504 Test[56342:707] seekVideo: 2000