# How to get elements of html,xml by hpple ( xpath )?

Tags: iphone, html, xml, xpath, hpple

please use hpple(xpath),  This is a followup to my previous question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723244/iphone-how-to-select-this-label
```

How can I get the number in `seekVideo(number)`? For example:

```
<a href="#" class="transcriptLink" onclick="seekVideo(2000); return false;"
```

I want to get "2000".

I have tried:

```
NSArray *elements = [xpathParser search:@"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')'))"];
```

But that's not right. How should i  do this?

If someone can you use the code framework named hpple(xpath) , it would be great.

this is my code for get text ,now how to change for getting number?????

```
  #define WebSite @"http://www.ted.com/talks/matt_cutts_try_something_new_for_30_days.html"

- (void)setLoadData
{
    NSData *siteData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WebSite]];



    TFHpple *xpathParser = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:siteData];
    NSArray *elements = [xpathParser search:@"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/a[number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick, '('), ')')) >2000]/text()"];

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (TFHppleElement *element in elements) 
    {

        NSString *strs = [element content];
        NSLog(@"cc: %@", strs);
        [arr addObject:strs];
        NSLog(@"arr: %@", arr);

    }
    self.listData = arr;
    [arr release];
    [xpathParser release];
}
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation of the problem and for a correct XPath expression that evaluates to the wanted number.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried:

```
     NSArray *elements = [xpathParser
 search:@"//div[@id='transcriptText']/div/p/number(substring-before(substring-after(@onclick,
 '('), ')'))"];
```

> But that's not right. How should i do ?

**In XPath 1.0 it is syntactically illegal to have a function call as a location step**.

Try:

```
substring-before(substring-after(.../a/@onclick, 'seekVideo('), 
                 ')'
                 )
```

Or try:

```
number(
       substring-before(substring-after(.../a/@onclick, 'seekVideo('), 
                        ')'
                        )
       )
```

where `...` must be substituted with the XPath expression that selects the parent of `a`.

Comment: can you give me real code of "where ... must be substituted with the XPath expression that selects the parent of a."

Comment: @libai: I have used "..." because you haven't provided any XML document on which you want to evaluate the XPath expression. It is *you* that must provide it. If you don't understand this very basic fact, then you are wasting the time of many readers -- and definitely your time, too. Please, edit your question, provide the XML document you want to work with it (a minimal document is best) and then notify me in a comment. There's nothing I can do until then. Remember -- we are not clairevoyants here ...

Comment: thank you , i have changed my question, waiting for your help ?

Comment: my first project of html ,  so need more details helps